# How do I block GRUB from appearing when resuming from hibernation?

Tags: boot, grub2, hibernate

When my computer boots up after being shut down, GRUB has a timeout. I want the same behavior after waking up from hibernation. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

EDIT: here's a clarification of the current and desired behaviors:

**Currently** when I open laptop after hibernation, GRUB appears and has no timeout.

I **do not want** GRUB to appear while resuming after hibernation.

Comment: @the_Seppi you might want to add that as answer.

Comment: @the_Seppi: GRUB does appear after hibernation, though. I'd be happy if it didn't, also. I basically never use my other OS, so if GRUB always jumped into its first choice then I'd be happy.

Answer (score 4):

A bug causes GRUB to look for this line instead:

GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/462888/comments/10

Answer (score 0):

"It's not a bug, it's a feature." You aren't supposed to boot another OS while the one is hibernated. This is to prevent the loss of data by SWAP access of the other OS. Hibernation is meant for quick resume of the hibernated OS.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. GRUB does appear after hibernation (sans timeout) and I want it to either not appear or to appear with timeout.

Comment: try this: in /etc/default/grub  set GRUB_TIMEOUT=10 to 0  As the file says run #update-grub  after making changes.

Comment: With these settings GRUB still appears sometimes: GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="Ubuntu"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nosplash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"

Comment: `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="true"`

Comment: "aren't supposed to boot another OS while the one is hibernated" --
Why not? I do it all the time (between two Linux installations) and nice to have full state restored for each one.